# process.waitFor is stuck

Tags: java, java-11

In below java code, I see that `process.waitFor()` seems to not exit. I have set `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` which should help me to redirect error with standard output and am reading the `inputStream` in method `readProcessOutput`. I thought when we read all the output and error streams the process should exit. But currently its struck. Can I please know how to solve this?
Also, I am using which sets standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process.

```
        ...
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("sh",
                "test.sh");
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        List<String> results = readProcessOutput(process.getInputStream());
        setExitCode(process.waitFor());
        ...

    private List<String> readProcessOutput(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
        return lines;
    }

    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitCode;
    }

    private void setExitCode(int exitCode) {
        this.exitCode = exitCode;
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to share that script you're running?

Comment: @Arun Shankar Obviously, it is stuck in `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)`. To know what is happening we need to know, when you run `runCarXmlSampleMatcher.sh` in terminal what is the output vs the output you are collecting in `readProcessOutput`?

Comment: Your code works for me. Obviously I can't run _runCarXmlSampleMatcher.sh_ but I ran a simple shell script. Note that when I remove the call to method [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()), `lines` is not empty but it is if I keep the call to `inheritIO`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks.. Yes I did see that the code works fine for other scripts but for this. So, will check from script itself.